# Angular getComputedStyle from SCSS

Tags: javascript, angular, sass

i am trying to get the computed style from SCSS file but it returns an empty string.
is there another way to get the getComputedStyle from SCSS ?

Angular Component:

```
ngOnInit(): void { 
 const elem = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
 const colorTest = elem.getPropertyValue('test').trim();
console.log(colorTest); //equal to '' instead of red Hex Code
}
```

SCSS File:

> $test : red;

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-csqmh9?file=src/app/app.component.scss)

Comment: Hello @Ala and welcome to stackoverflow, it is recommended to give us where and how did you coded the two lines in your component to understand the issue

Comment: Could you try with  window.getComputedStyle and not getComputedStyle?

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez inside ngOnInit on Angular 13.
```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const elem = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
    const colorTest = elem.getPropertyValue('test').trim();
    console.log(colorTest);
  }
```

Comment: @Ala thank you for your answer, but it would be recommended to add this to your previous Post please to share with all people so that all people can help you.  Also we need your SCSS file or at least the container block of your `$test: red` code, because there is no "$test" property in scss (until you wrote a custom expression on it), you can alsoreproduce your issue in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/). To learn more about this community, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and its linked resources.

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-csqmh9?file=src/app/app.component.scss)

Comment: @Pterrat it doesn't work, thanks

Comment: @Ala The thing you're trying to achieve is not possible as scss variables only exists on compile time and they have nothing to do with angular/typescript/javascript. if you really want to declare a variable in css and want to manipulate it in your code then try [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

Comment: @Yogi understood ,it is the right response, thank you for the feedback